# Could a dystopian society control non-perishable foods to prevent escape / mutiny?

Tags: biology, society, religion

Here are some sub questions:

- Are there habitable earth environments where non- perishables (even raisins and honey) are hard to discover?
- Are there agents that could be added to make foods more perishable? (like a 24 hour time bomb)
- Are there plausible religious or evolutionary justifications that would maintain this belief or behavior throughout the society without deception from an oppressive class?

Comment: Too many questions. Can you please ask just one question?

Comment: Apart from there being too many questions, do you really mean ***DIS***topian, or do you mean ***DYS***topian.  There is a difference.  Otherwise, welcome! and please take a look at the [help] and [tour] so you can get a good idea what we mean by "too many questions" and how to write a good question and what kinds of questions are acceptable here, etc, etc.

Comment: They could always enact the [lysine contingency](https://jurassicpark.fandom.com/wiki/Lysine_contingency)...

Comment: Sorry, I asked too many questions. Thanks everyone who engaged it anyway and welcomed me to the site.

FWIW, @elemtilas, I couldn't see a specific taboo against my style of question just skimming the links you gave, but I'm new to the community and take your word that it's not in the spirit of "practical, objective" questions to ask so many at once. I will try to break mine up in the future!

Comment: I wasn't complaining about your style so much as your supernumerariosity. You really do need to edit three of them out.  That's not a bad thing!  That just means you get to ask three other individual questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeasts and bacteria can be added to foods to make them spoil fairly quickly. Fermentation would be my go to choice on this one. Even wild honey will ferment when just a little water is added to it and raisins contain loads of wild yeast already.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to address the main question, as the sub questions are kind of against the rules of this site.

**A dystopian society could stop the production of perishable food**

There are two methods for doing it. The first is to only produce one food, Soylent. No, not *[that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soylent_Green)* one, *[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soylent_(meal_replacement))* one, the all-in-one meal supplement. It's got a shelf life of 72 hours once opened, so the way to do this is have Soylent given in open canisters to the civilians. It had the added benefit of giving your dystopian society a single tasteless food, which I have to say is dramatically appropriate for such a society.

The second way is to only have them be able to eat in specified buildings which food is delivered to in sealed packages and anyone who dares leaves with food gets repeatedly shot on sight.